# Ignore/bypass - Datastax Cassandra NoHostAvailableException

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax

I am running a springboot application that writes some log info to cassandra and everything works fine.
Now there are some situations where the application will not have connectivity to these cassandra servers (for instance when it is deployed in an integration environment for QA).
Spring does not start the application in such cases and simply terminates the application with a `"NoHostAvailableException"`. Is there a way to tell spring to simply ignore this and continue with starting the application? I tries using `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true` but it had no effect.